# function scope using `eval` and `local`

Tags: r

I have a function to evaluate a list of expressions and return a value based on which expression evaluates to true. Here are my expressions and values:

```
myexprs = list(expression(x <= 5), expression(x > 5 & x < 7), expression(x >= 7))
myvals = c(0, 1, 0)
```

I make a function that returns a function to evaluate a given number using `myexprs` and `myvals`. I use `lapply` to evaluate the expressions and return the value of `myvals` that matches which expression in `myexprs` evaluates to `TRUE`. If I do:

```
hscd = function(expr, score){
  function(x) score[unlist(lapply(expr, function(e) local(eval(e))))]
}  

test = hscd(myexprs, myvals)
test(4)
test(6)
test(7)
```

It works. However, if I do

```
hscd = function(expr, score){
  function(x) score[unlist(lapply(expr, local))]
}  

test = hscd(myexprs, myvals)
test(4)
```

It breaks.

**My question:** Why do I need to do `local(eval(expr))` rather than just doing `local(expr)`? From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) it seems like the latter method should work too.

---

*for completeness*: If I do

```
hscd = function(expr, score){
  function(x) score[unlist(lapply(expr, eval))]
}  

test = hscd(myexprs, myvals)
test(4)
```

The function breaks because it looks for the variable `x` outside of the internal function, which mostly makes sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note from the `local` help page that

> [`local`] is equivalent to `evalq` except that its default argument creates a new, empty environment.

So what's happening is that your first parameter is being quoted. Note that these return the same result and neither evaluates the expression:

```
local(myexprs[[1]])
evalq(myexprs[[1]])
```

You could use `eval()` with an explicit environment rather than `local()`

```
hscd = function(expr, score){
  function(x) score[unlist(lapply(expr, eval, envir=environment()))]
}
```

Comment: Very clear. I wonder if this is why I could never get `local` to deliver the results I intended?

Comment: Thank you! Part of my mistake was also misinterpreting `parent.frame()` and thinking it returned what is actually the result of `environment()`. This clears up the third example in my question too.