# R variable value successfully enters function as input parameter but is later removed automatically

Tags: r, function

I am running a function (called getHyphen in MWE below) that requires two input parameters (called group1 and group2 in MWE below). When I call the function, I receive an error as follows:

```
 Error in paste0(group1, "-", group2) : object 'group1' not found
```

To try to resolve this, I decided to print the value of 'group1' in the middle of the function. The value of 'group1' seems to be correct and present inside the function at the first two print locations, however, it disappears before the third print location, even though I do not remove it. You can see this in the MWE below:

```
library(limma)
getHyphen <- function(group1=group1, group2=group2){
  print(c("first print group1", group1))
  group <- as.factor(unlist(lapply(c("A.1","A.2","B.1","B.2","C.1","C.2"), function (x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[.]"))[1])))
  design <- model.matrix(~0+group)
  colnames(design) <- gsub("group", "", colnames(design))
  print(c("second print group1", group1))
  contr.matrix <- makeContrasts(eval(paste0(group1,"-",group2)), levels = colnames(design))
  print(c("third print group1", group1))
  return(contr.matrix)
}

getHyphen(group1="A", group2="B")
```

Now, I can achieve the desired result with the code simply as below:

```
group1="A"; group2="B"
group <- as.factor(unlist(lapply(c("A.1","A.2","B.1","B.2","C.1","C.2"), function (x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[.]"))[1])))
design <- model.matrix(~0+group)
colnames(design) <- gsub("group", "", colnames(design))
contr.matrix <- makeContrasts(eval(paste0(group1,"-",group2)), levels = colnames(design))
```

However, this is only feasible in my MWE. My real code is much larger and needs to be set into a function. Any ideas how to resolve my problem so that I can call getHyphen(group1="A", group2="B) without getting that error?

Thank you for any input!

EDIT: Resolved

I think I found the solution: You have to put the input parameter name in front of paste0(group1,"-",group2). In this case, the input parameter name is contrasts. So, the new code would now have the line:

```
contr.matrix <- makeContrasts(contrasts=eval(paste0(group1,"-",group2)), levels = colnames(design))
```

Instead of:

```
contr.matrix <- makeContrasts(eval(paste0(group1,"-",group2)), levels = colnames(design))
```

Comment: Where does `makeContrasts()` come from? That doesn't appear to be a base R function so I can't run your code.

Comment: Your Problem is not reproducible. However, it might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840397/function-scope-using-eval-and-local.

Comment: If I make a dummy `makeContrasts` that just returns TRUE, the code works. So it's definitely an issue with makeContrasts. It's super weird that you would use `eval` where you're using it by the way and that's probably the cause of the problem. Why is that there?

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. I apologize and I added the relevant library call.

Comment: Thank you @MikeStanley. Actually, I tentatively think eval() is not necessary. I am not sure why I thought it was before, but I checked my real code, and I think it might not be necessary. Regardless, removing eval() seems to replicate the problem. So, maybe it is something with makeContrasts.